# Communicate between 2 applications

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have written a basic VB winform application (in visual studio) that control the lights. I published and create an install package so I can install this on other PCs.
My questions is how to sync these applications to communicate with one another so if I turn a light on, on one PC, other PC will sense that and display it on thier application.

I can use timer to see if there are any action every 15 second, but I don’t think this is efficient way.

Comment: How does your application control the lights? Bluetooth, RF, zigbee?

Comment: thorough WIFI  and other PCs have IP address assign to them

Comment: Also, the lights are Philips Hue with Bridge

Comment: How do you check if the light is on?

Comment: You should look into TCP connections.

Comment: I am using their API.  using Get to POST to do on and off action on lights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196262/how-do-i-send-messages-from-one-computer-to-another-using-vb-net) question that involves sending information between computers over a network. You could have the program send what it did to the lights so that the other programs can update themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look at writing the status to a file accessible to all on the network, use the filewatcher class to detect changes to the file, and when the file changes read it from all PCs to see the current status of everything.

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

another option would be to use UDP broadcasting